# How i can fix this error :Cannot convert value of type 'NSURL' to expected argument type 'URLRequest'

Tags: ios, swift

i was use it solution but it's not work

```
 let targetURL = URL(string: request)
 let request = URLRequest(url: targetURL!)
```

this is my code

```
import UIKit

class WebUIViewController: UIViewController,UIWebViewDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var smartWebView: UIWebView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityWebload: UIActivityIndicatorView!
    var smart :String?
```

i am pass url by first view controller using smart variable  and i print url in console but cant show in my web view

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
     // MARK: - Web View Controller
    func webScreen(){
        let request = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: smart!)
        smartWebView.loadRequest(request)

        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        activityWebload.startAnimating()
    }
    func webViewDidStartLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
        activityWebload.stopAnimating()
    }

    @IBAction func refreshpage(_ sender: Any) {
        smartWebView.reload()
    }

}
```

Comment: What's the question? What does "it's not work" mean? What does this question have to do with arrays? What does it have to do with JSON? What is the point of your first code — you mention `targetURL` but your _real_ code never mentions it? And finally, what's the point of your `webScreen` method? No code ever calls it, so nothing will ever happen.

Comment: What is `smart` supposed to be, a local file URL or a network URL? The error message is quite clear. `UIWebView.loadRequest` expects an input argument of type `URLRequest`, not `NSURL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your URL is Correct or not after to open in webView

```
 if let url = URL(string: "Your Url"){
      if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {

           let request = URLRequest(url: url)
           smartWebView.loadRequest(request)
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong:

```
let request = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: smart!)
smartWebView.loadRequest(request) //The parameter here should 
                                  //be of type URLRequest
```

The first line creates request as an NSURL. You name it `request` but it's not a `URLRequest`

The function `UIWebView.loadRequest(_:)` wants a parameter of type `URLRequest`, not `URL` or `NSURL`. You need to add a line to create a URL request from the URL:

```
//First create a URL object
let theURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: smart!)

//Now use the URL to create a ULRRequest object
let request = URLRequest(url: theURL)

//Use the URLRequest to submit the load request. 
smartWebView.loadRequest(request)
```

(Note that you don't need to create an Objective-C `NSURL`. You can use the native Swift `URL` type.)